# output not being printed

Tags: python, printing, output

hi guys im getting crazy with this code, so basically i'm making a script (that was supposed to be quite easy) to calculate the uncertainty of the quantities (fisics) but basically one of the outputs **errore_relativo** is just not being printed
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaKbq.png

here is the code

```
from xml.dom.minidom import Element
from simple_term_menu import TerminalMenu
data = []
med = ""
errore_assoluto = ""
errore_relativo = ""
errore_percentuale = ""
def erroreassoluto():
    global errore_assoluto
    data.sort()
    errore1 = data[-1] - data[0]
    errore_assoluto = errore1 / 2
#    print(data)
#    print ("l'errore assoluto è ",errore_assoluto)
def media():
    global med
    datalen = len(data)
    datasum = sum(data)
    datalen = int(datalen)
    datasum = int(datasum)
    med = datasum / datalen
    med = int(med)
#    print ("media: ", med)

#
#        su questo ci stiamo lavorando
#

def errorerelativo():
    global errore_assoluto
    global errore_relativo
    global med
    # float(errore_assoluto)
    # float(med)
    errore_relativo = errore_assoluto / med
    errore_relativo = int(errore_relativo)
# def errorepercentuale():
#      errore_relativo = int(errore_relativo)
#      errore_percentuale = errore_relativo / 100
#      print (errore_percentuale)
def datain():
    p = input("insert a measure: ")
    if p == "":
        p = 0
    p = int(p)
    data.append(p)
    otherdata()
def otherdata():
    options = ["yes","no"]
    terminal_menu = TerminalMenu(options, title="options")
    menu_entry_index = terminal_menu.show()
    if menu_entry_index == 0:
        datain()
    if menu_entry_index == 1:
        calc()
def calc():
    erroreassoluto()
    media()
    #errorerelativo()
    #errorepercentuale()
datain()
print("media: ", med)
print("errore assoluto: ", errore_assoluto)  
print("errore relativo: ", errore_relativo)
```

i'm sorry that the code is in italian but you know this is for my personal use so i'd like to understand it.

i commented out some parts of code that i'm not using right now or that are still not ready.

Comment: errore_relativo IS being printed but still has a value of an empty string. Set the variable to something like "xxx" at the top of the code instead of "" and you will see this happening.

Comment: ok then can i ask you why the function errorerelativo() is not changing the variable?

Comment: I can't see that you are calling errorerelativo() anywhere,